# How to refactor adding properties to json through nvl2 to avoid repetition?

Tags: sql, json, oracle

We are creating json of tag names and respective tag values:

```
[
  "name": "bob",
  "surname": "dylan",
  ...
]
```

This is done through first creating a main select, and then through that including tens of `nvl2` functions to call the appropriate procedures for getting the value of each tag:

```
select u_json_pck.JsonPropertyObject(null,
           nclob_tt(
                    nvl2(ExecuteSelectToCheckIfValueExists(),
                         U_JSON_PCK.JsonProperty('TAG_NAME', ExecuteAVerySimilarSelectToGetValue()), 
                         decode(v_remove_empty_tags, 1, 
                                U_JSON_PCK.JsonProperty('TAG_NAME', ''), null)),
                    nvl2(......),
                    nvl2(...)...
```

(1) check if any value exists (e.g., for a tag "meetingParticipants" no participants might exist)
(2) if it exists, then call the procedure that actually gets that value and forms it into necessary nclob, and add this and the tag to json
(3) if it doesn't exist, then check if empty tags should be added to json, and then either add an empty one or don't add one

Can this be refactored so that `ExecuteSelectToCheckIfValueExists()` isn't called at all? We could check `v_remove_empty_tags` in the `ExecuteAVerySimilarSelectToGetValue()` and then, if this function finds no results, return `-1` or `null`. But how to form the appropriate json out of that result?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your function `u_json_pck` and type `nclob_tt` do exactly, but why not do this with the built-in JSON syntax something like:

```
select json_object
         ( 'myobject' value json_arrayagg
                            ( json_object
                                ( 'tag_name1'  value value1
                                , 'tag_name2'  value value2
                                , 'tag_name3'  value value3
                                absent on null
                                ) 
                              returning clob
                             )
         ) json_data
  from
  ( select null value1, 'BBB' value2, 'CCC' value3 from dual
    union all
    select null value1, 'BBB' value2, null value3 from dual
    union all
    select 123 value1, null value2, 'DDD' value3 from dual
    union all
    select 456 value1, 'EEE' value2, null value3 from dual
  );
```

which returns:

```
{
  "myobject": [
    {
      "tag_name2": "BBB",
      "tag_name3": "CCC"
    },
    {
      "tag_name2": "BBB"
    },
    {
      "tag_name1": 123,
      "tag_name3": "DDD"
    },
    {
      "tag_name1": 456,
      "tag_name2": "EEE"
    }
  ]
}
```

You just need to change `absent on null` to `null on null` according to the value of `v_remove_empty_tags` - so either have a separate `select` statement for each, or construct the SQL dynamically to specify that.